# 'Anytime' and 'ever'

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech, subcontinental-english, early-modern-english

Actually I am a non native English speaker, of course I may come across many confusion but I don't care of those much,but curious some times to know about the things.

I know the meaning of 'Ever' which is 'At Anytime' and 'Always'.

I found there is a slight difference between 'Ever' and 'Anytime' when we use this.

Example:

1. you can come at anytime.  ---> here 'Anytime' means a specific time of the day but not determined.
2. Have you ever seen this? ---> here 'Ever' says 'anytime', however any time of  any day not any time of the particular day.

Is that the way you think?

Appreciate your response

Comment: “*ever*” means “at any time in the past or in the future” not “at anytime”

Comment: "Any time" should really be 2 separate words. Smooshing them together is informal.

Comment: Sunil, those examples are both much simpler and much more complicated than they look.

*you can come at any time* might mean *a specific time* but *not determined* and that would depend why it’s not also *a time determined* but *not specified.*
 
Either way, it can’t be clear whether *… at any time* means *just turn up without notice* or *let me know in advance.*

Meanwhile *have you ever seen this* in no way refers to any time or day; it refers to your entire life.

Answer (score 1):

*Ever* is a special [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), a suppletion for the nonexistent **anywhen*.

As an NPI, *ever* can only occur in negative contexts, which include questions, comparatives,  and *if*-clauses, as well as many [negative trigger words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) like *not, seldom, doubt, only,* and *surprised*.

- *He has **not ever** seen this.*
- *He **seldom ever** looks at it.*
- *I **doubt** he's **ever** seen it.*
- ***Only*** his wife has **ever** seen it.
- *I'm **surprised** he's **ever** seen it.*

But remove the negative trigger and *ever* becomes ungrammatical.

- **He has **ever** seen this.*
- **He **ever** looks at it.*
- **I think he's **ever** seen it.*
- **Even his wife has **ever** seen it.*
- **I'm pleased he's **ever** seen it.*

*Anytime* (or *any time*) is also an NPI, but it's not suppletive, and has a range of usage beyond that of *ever*. For one thing, *anytime* has the 'free choice' sense of *any*, like *you can do it anytime* = 'choose a time, and you can do it then'. This is not possible with *ever*, which is strictly limited to negative contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the word 'ever' has *two* meanings.

'Have you ever seen ...?' = at any time in the past.

'For ever' = always (thinking of the future).

'You can come at any time' is nothing to do with the word 'ever'.

Comment: This, I think, is too dogmatic. "Have you ever seen X" = "Have you seen at any time in the past."